# Rails: error when including javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some JavaScript on another, non-Rails, site that works for browser side sort of tables. If I reference this in my Rails app from the external site, it works fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://10.1.10.36/sort.js"></script>
```

If I put it in the assets/javascripts folder, I get an error:

```
Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError in Taxes#index
Showing /home/asa/Rails/home/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #8 raised:
"\xA3" on UTF-8
```

Can you point me to what this error is, why I am getting it, how do I fix it?

I did find a reference that says name it sort.js.erb and include the line:

```
<%# encoding: utf-8 %>
```

But that made no difference.

Alternately, is there a way I can put this JavaScript on the site and use a fixed reference it? I have had no success in doing that.

Comment: What's on line 8 of your `application.html.haml`? Are you sure you're saving your templates as UTF-8?

Comment: to move the script source into your app, you'd copy it to `app/assets/javascripts` and add a `require` line to `application.js`. See [http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization)

Answer (score 0):

This file reference belongs into your

```
layouts/application.rb
```

file or whatever layout you use for your view. Put it into the

```
<header>
```

section of that file and it will work fine. 
Otherwise take a read at

[TheAsset Pipeline of rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbeled upon the same issue and solved it by converting the Javascript file to utf-8 Format.
Before:

> $file -i sorttable.js
>   sorttable.js: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Conversion:

> $ iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 sorttable.js -o sort.js

Remove old file, rename new file...

Result:

> $ file -i sorttable.js
>   sorttable.js: text/html; charset=utf-8

And no more errors in the Debugger Console.